# Converting Report's Run time from GMT to CST in Power BI Report Builder

Tags: powerbi

As you know, Power BI Service display time in GMT. Our customers need the report's run time to be in CST. What is the best way to convert the time to CST? Subtracting a 5 hours might be alright for now, but that would be impacted when daylight savings time changes. At the moment, report is using &ExcecutionTime to display date and time at the end of the report.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Seyed

Comment: Nitpicking a bit here, but what you are saying indicates that you don't actually want CST, which is always defined as 6 hours behind UTC.

Comment: Depending on the daylight saving time being on or off, there will be either 5 hours or 6 hours time difference. At the moment, GMT is 5 hours ahead. I am thinking to just subtract 5 from &ExecutionTime, but whatever I tried hasn't worked.